# Why does mat-form-field increase its height when I add a new item to child mat-chip-list?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a `mat-chip-list` inside a `mat-form-field`. Whenever I add a new `mat-chip` to the list, the height of the `mat-form-field` increases. What isn't correct in my code that I get such behaviour?

HTML:

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-chip-list #contacts>
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let type of addedContactTypes" [selectable]="true" [removable]="true"
                    (remove)="removeContact(type)">
            <mat-icon [svgIcon]="contactTypeToDataMap.get(type).iconName"></mat-icon>
            <span class="margin-left-0-5rem">{{event[contactTypeToDataMap.get(type).fieldName]}}</span>
            <mat-icon matChipRemove svgIcon="cancel"></mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
          <input placeholder="Контакты"
                 [matChipInputFor]="contacts"
                 [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeyCodes"
                 [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="true"
                 (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addContact($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
      </mat-form-field>
```

The screenshot of the behaviour:

[image: The screen of the behaviour]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chips are jumping to the next line because they do not fit inside the `mat-form-field` component. To fix this add to your CSS:

```
mat-form-field {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The problem fixed. Thank you! You just saved my time!

Comment: Even in chips demo in angular material page they have a class with `width: 100%` attached to `mat-form-field`. I too ran into similar case where I have `mat-form-field` enclosed inside a `div`. I solved it by attaching the same class with width 100% to all those enclosing `divs`